# data transfer through loop in excel vb

Tags: vba, excel

i have this kind of data in excel file

Exportfile.xlsx

```
      A        B
1)    Head  31-Dec-2017
2)    a         23
3)    b         45
4)    c         46
```

Datasheet.xlsx

And in datasheet data like this

```
1)           **A**  
2) ***QUARTER          Data***
3) 31 Mar 2017  
4) 30 Jun 2017  
5) 30 Sep 2017  
6) 31 Dec 2017  
7)  
8)  
9)         **B**    
10) ***QUARTER          Data***
11) 31 Mar 2017 
12) 30 Jun 2017 
13) 30 Sep 2017 
14) 31 Dec 2017 
15) 
16) 
17)         **C**   
18) ***QUARTER          Data***
19) 31 Mar 2017 
20) 30 Jun 2017 
21) 30 Sep 2017 
22) 31 Dec 2017
```

now i want to paste values from exportfile to datasheet and want data like this

```
1)           **A**  
2) ***QUARTER          Data***
3) 31 Mar 2017  
4) 30 Jun 2017  
5) 30 Sep 2017  
6) 31 Dec 2017         23
7)  
8)  
9)         **B**    
10) ***QUARTER          Data***
11) 31 Mar 2017 
12) 30 Jun 2017 
13) 30 Sep 2017 
14) 31 Dec 2017          45
15) 
16) 
17)         **C**   
18) ***QUARTER          Data***
19) 31 Mar 2017 
20) 30 Jun 2017 
21) 30 Sep 2017 
22) 31 Dec 2017          46
```

now i do this code

```
Sub copy_data(File_Name)
   For i = 2 To 4
Windows("Exportfile.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("ESheet").Select
         Cells(i, 2).Select
     Selection.Copy
Windows(File_Name).Activate
    Sheets("Dsheet").Select
   On Error Resume Next
  **j = '' here what i do** 
    Cells(j, 2).Select
   On Error Resume Next
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

Next
End Sub
```

now in above code on J line what should i do so values copy from export file and paste in datasheet in quarter 31 Dec 2017 through loop

any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the template is static, as described, this is just math. Declare and initialize a variable `start` outside `for` with 6 and add a formula inside the loop for j

```
j = start + ((i-2) *8)
```

Comment: if this is not static then ? and i declare like this 
Dim start= 6 this shows an error Compile error : Expected end of statement

Comment: and actually this is dummy data my actual data position is different like in exportfile range is 1802 to 1840 .. and in datasheet data where i paste position is 60,88,116,144 ,172,200,228,256,284,312,340,368,396,452,480,508,536,564,592,620,648,676,704,732,760

Comment: `Dim start as Integer` on first line and then `start = 6`. Now, it doesn't matter where your data starts and how is structured, by static I meant that is fixed and therefore you can apply a formula as above. I recommend to put the formula on paper and calculated few values to fully understand it. `start` is used for the first value because `I-2` equals 0 multiplied by 8 is 0. 8 is the distance between two rows, so `(i-2)*8` jumps from 6 8 rows each iteration. Just change the variables with the actual data you have in your file.

Comment: yeah ..i do that.. now  i have data start from 1803 and end at 1840 in export file .. so in Datasheet for A last quarter 31 Dec 2017 position is 60.. so according o forumla =1803 + ((1803-2)*8) this equals to 16211. so this position 16211 position where actual position is 60 .. hope you understand

Comment: and in actual data difference is 27 .. so i place 27 instead of 8 ?

Comment: It's close. First value of `start` refers to the first position in your Data sheet, not export, so it's 60. `(i-2)` becomes `(i-3)`, because the iteration starts from 1803, you need to make a 0 on the first loop. Then 8, yes , becomes 27.